# Overloading the getCause() method in a throwable object

Tags: java, throwable

How would one go about overloading the getCause() method in a throwable object ?
I have the following but it doesn't seem to work as it says that it cannot be overloaded with a string.

```
public class MyException extends RuntimeException   {
String cause;
MyException(String s)   {
    cause = s;
}
@Overwrite public String getCause()    {
    return cause;
}
```

Comment: Whats the point in overloading the `cause` property of exceptions this way? You can already supply a customized string message. The `cause` property is intended to reflect the next immediate causing exception in an *exception chain*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is illegal to have two methods that only differ in their return type.  Suppose someone wrote:

```
Object obj = myException.getCause();
```

That is perfectly legal java, and the compiler has no way to figure out if it's the `String` version or the `Throwable` version.

Likewise you can't replace the superclass signature since this is also perfectly legal:

```
Throwable t = new MyException();
Throwable t0 = t.getCause();
//Returns String?!?!?!?
```

Comment: Thanks, So the only way to do this would be to change the method name ? Is there a build in way of saving the cause of the exception ?

Comment: You didn't describe in the question your actual goal as far as a new feature, so no idea what the *this* that you're looking for a way how to do is! :)

Comment: sorry :) by saying this I mean when I throw and exception I pass the reason through as a string to be saved in the cause string, the getCause would return the cause in the catch block of my code.

Comment: That's what `getMessage` is there for.

Comment: Thanks, so if I understand correctly the throwable object class can internally store the message by saying for example setMessage("error....") in the constructor and then just using getMessage to retrieve it ?

Comment: it's a constructor arg, not a setter, sorry, but yes

Answer (score 1):

**Accepted answer clears the point** :

> It is illegal to have two methods that only differ in their return
>   type

**But if you have a situation where, `getCause()` should return the custom cause in `MyException`, in case original cause is null.**

In that case, you can use `initCause()` to set the cause and override `toString()` method. So, when `getCause()` method will be called on object of `MyException`, it will show the message from customCause instead of null.

**What is the use:** In legacy system, if you have used `getCause()` on `MyException` object while logging, and now you want to add the custom cause to it without changing lot of code, here is the way.

```
    public class MyException extends RuntimeException {
        String customCause;

        MyException(String s) {
            super(s);
            customCause = s;
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized Throwable getCause() {
            if (super.getCause() != null) {
                return this;
            } else {
                this.initCause(new Throwable(customCause));
                return this;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            String s = getClass().getName();
            String message = getLocalizedMessage();
            if (message == null) {
                message = customCause;
            }
            return (message != null) ? (s + ": " + message) : s;
        }
    }
```

References:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#initCause(java.lang.Throwable)
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html